# Ярошь или Ярош?

Tags: имена-собственные

Нашел информацию, что одной из производных форм имени Ярослав было имя Ярошь/Ярош. Если отбросить сайты, посвященные этимологии и толкованию имен, как ненадежные источники, то подобное можно встретить и на чешской Википедии (Jaroslav (též Jarin, Jarda, Jarek, Jára, **Jarouš**, Slávek) je mužské jméno), и в сборнике "Славянский именослов или Собрание славянских личных имен в алфавитном порядке", составленном священником М. Морышкиным.

Как правильно писать это имя: Ярошь или Ярош? Видел и то, и другое написание. Спасибо заранее за ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если имя древнерусское, то писаться оно могло только **Ярошь**, так как "ш" была бы мягкой. Во времена нынешние мягкий знак после шипящей воспринимается как обозначение того, что слово женского рода (*сушь, тишь, мышь*, но *муж, уж, малыш*). Поэтому имя представителя мужского пола я бы рекомендовал писать без мягкого знака, а если так названа представительница прекрасного пола, то с ним.

Comment: >Если имя древнерусское, то писаться оно могло только Ярошь, так как "ш" была бы мягкой.

А вот такое мягкое "ш" -- это вообще какая-то старинная, древнерусская особенность?

Мне приходилось слышать такой своеобразный говор, где "Ш" и "Ж" произносили мягко. В машь-ину (в машину, значит). Бижь-ить (бежит). Давно интересно было узнать, могло ли быть подобное произношение в старину? (слово "машина", конечно, не подходящий пример)

Или это просто местные жители произношение исказили? (хотя ЭТОТ вопрос скорее риторический)

Comment: Все шипящие, Ч и частично Ц в древнерусском языке были только мягкими. 
Ч и Щ мягкость сохранили, Ж и Ш отвердели. Полностью твердым стало еще и Ц. Произошдло это, вилимо, уже к XIV веку, хотя тут лингвоисторики несколько расходятся.

В современном русском смягчение Ш и Ж (уроме удвоенных) - диалектное и просторечное нарушение орфоэпической нормы.
 
В родственных языках оппозиция по твердости мягкости для шипящих и аффрикат сохранилось, типичный пример - украинский.

Answer (score 4):

С чем согласен, так это с тем, что сейчас не следует копировать древнерусское написание.
Поэтому лично я за **Ярош**.
С остальным - просто не знаю что сказать.
Не уверен даже, что все слова на шипящую в древнерусском писались с мягким знаком.
И то, что Ярош - однозначно уменьшительное к Ярослав - тоже. Могли быть и другие производящие, но вернее всего - это имя "само по себе".

Менее же всего уверен, что мужской и женский вариант имени (любого) могут допускать разное написание. Последнее, впрочем, вопрос умозрительный, вряд ли женщина могла носить подобное имя. Женские имена на Руси (до монголов) - это вообще особая статья, женщин звали в основном по отчествам...

Comment: В современности так могут и девочку назвать, для таких случаев и дана моя рекомендация по разделению написания в зависимости от пола.

Comment: Я понимаю смысл Вашей рекомендации, но совсем не уверен в её правильности.
Что же касается современного написания, то против написания с мягим знакам.
Вы т.н. "новый звательный" (Маш, Саш, Наташ: "Маш, поди сюда!") будете с мягким знаком писать? Я - нет. Хотя признаться, когда-то, впервые столкнувшись с этим вопросом, допускал такой вариант).

Comment: Однозначно Ярош. Так же как и Матиаш, Андраш и пр.

Comment: gecube, Ярош может иметь не только мадьярское происхождение. Скорее всего - западнославянское, как Витош. И в этом случае аналогия с Матиашем и Бартошем сомнительна.

Comment: @behemothus, ну, регион он там один, да и [Матиаш запросто может быть чехом][1] :-) а [Томаш - поляком][2]

[1]:https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD,_%D0%99%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%88
[2]:https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BD,_%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88

Comment: Язык-то разный... Для Томаша и Матиаша нет славянских производящих. А Витош, например, это Витольд.